# Why is the frequency ppm different between machines when using chrony to sync system clock?

Tags: chrony

I'm a newer to Linux, and I met a problem when using chrony to synchronize the system clock. There is a machine A and it's a ntp server, and I want machine B and machine C to sync time to A. The configuration file in machine B and machine C /etc/chrony.conf is as follows:

```
server 172.x.x.x  # this is ip of ntp server
makestep 1.0 -1 # is this right?
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
local startum 10
allow
```

and here is my question:
After few hours synchronization, the system time of these machines are nearly the same(microseconds different). But when I use the **chronyc tracking** in machine B, I found the Frequency part shows:
**2024 ppm slow**
while in machine C:
**1.024 ppm**

Is the frequency ppm of machine B normal?

I tried to make another machine D to synchronize the system clock of ntp server A. And by chronyc tracking, I can see the Frequency: 2.104 ppm slow. So I doubt whether there is some wrong with the machine B (maybe the network delay or the hardware?).